# Capture something specific within a string with a Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex

Not quite sure what I should do at this point..I am utilizing a regular expression to capture JSON within the HTML on a website. I've initialized a for loop to go through everyline in the array to find **{"page_cur":**

I've attempted to push it to an array with the following code.
 
`line.push(json_text)`

 The result was the entire sites source code. What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'json'

mechanize = Mechanize.new

url = mechanize.get('http://www.hypem.com/')
page = Array.new
page = url.body.split(/\n/) 
json_text = Array.new

#look through every line of code
for line in page 

    #find {"page_cur": 
    next unless line =~ /^\s*\{"page_cur":/  
        #delete </script> tag on the last line
        line.sub! /<.script>/, '' 
        #push into array?

end
```

Comment: you need `()` to capture things...

Comment: where is this on the page. Your best bet is to navigate to the location on the page then parse the JSON. Also `next if` means skip the line if it matches this pattern which is currently from the start of a string with an indeterminate amount of spaces then `\{"page_cur":`

Comment: I was trying to use `next unless` after I saw your comment and changed the operator from `==` to `=~`

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to push into the json_text array it should be `json_text.push(line)`

Comment: Well it definitely pushed line into json_text, but it pushed the entire source code and not the snippet of JSON.

Comment: Or just `json_text << line` but either way if the given page is correct this does not exist anywhere in the page body.